# Has Android Jetpack Compose Beta detached builder of onCommit{}?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

Recently I update a compose project to Jetpack Compose Beta1. Because the project was built based on alpha, some methods are easily being migrated to the Beta1, however, the `onCommit{}` cannot be found anymore, has it been detached already?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's not the case anymore. These functions such as `onActive`, `onCommit` and `onDispose` are replaced with **SideEffect API** since `1.0.0-alpha11`

https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1548515